# How to remove a space between two printed things python

Tags: python

i and URL gets printed with a space between them like this : "482 URL" 
How do I get these things printed with no space between?

```
URL = input("Paste URL")
x=range(2,499)
for i in x:
    print(URL,i,end='\n')
```

Comment: `print(URL + i + “\n”)`

Comment: `print(f"{URL}{i}")`

Answer (score 1):

There is an option in print to use any kind of separation `sep` (similar to `end`)

In your case

```
URL = input("Paste URL")
x=range(2,499)
for i in x:
    print(URL,i,end='\n',sep='')
```

Comment: woah, that's even better. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
URL = input("Paste URL")
x=range(2,499)
for i in x:
    print(URL+str(i),end='\n')
```